# Rails Controller id Equals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a little new to rails, so pardon the noobish question.

I have a blog type application in rails using mongoid that has a users section and a comments section. (The comments are embedded within the article). So I was having trouble with the delete method of my comments controller. In order to delete them I traverse my collection, and look for where the id that the user clicked, the params[:id] equals the id in the database, the comment.id. Using print statements, I was able to find out that this does work and that the two id's should be equal. However, for some reason when I use the equals operator (==) in rails, it's registering the comment as nil.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    logger.debug(@article)
    @article.comments.each do |comment|
        logger.debug(comment)
        print comment.id.
        print ", "
        print params[:id]
        print " | "

        if comment.id.equal? params[:id]
            comment.destroy unless comment.nil?

        end 
    end 
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to "/" }
        format.js
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`comment.id` is a Bson object, `params[:id]` is a string.

They match when you print because what is displayed is `comment.id.to_s`

Anyway you'd rather do:

```
@article.comments.where(:id => params[:id]).first
```

Or:

```
@article.comments.where(:_id => params[:id]).first
```

I'm not sure for Mongoid.

Comment: print "#{comment.id.inspect}, #{params[:id].inspect} | " will show the difference between the id as an integer and the param as a string.

Comment: @MarlinPierce id in mongoid are BSON objects

Comment: The latter works in mongoid. Using Ruby 1.9 hash syntax, @article.comments.where(_id: params[:id]).first

Comment: @novemberkilo always funny people support answers but don't upvote :)

Comment: @apneadiving I was under the impression that upvotes are for answers that you find useful - or at least, that's what I've been doing during my limited time on Stack Overflow. In any case, here you go :)

Comment: @novemberkilo: thanks :) I generally upvotes good answers, simply